# Xamarin.Forms Android app reloads app on home pressed and picked up back

Tags: c#, android-activity, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Earlier it was working fine, and it was reloads only after back button pressed, now even if I press home button and pick it back from app stack it reloads app, like it was just opened, it is very useless, when user must to hide app, to read a payment code, to fill in payment form in my app.
And if user want to change his profile image, after making a photo all app reloads from start, downloading profile from web again, so is it ok, and I just need to save somewhere all states of my app and restore it bit by bit afted every hide, or there is a useful fix for it?

here is my app code:

```
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    private static bool _hasEverInited;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        if (!_hasEverInited)
        {
            InitGeo();
            Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);
            ShareImplementation.Init(this);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            ImageCircleRenderer.Init();
            InitData();
            _hasEverInited = true;
        }
            LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

my version of Xamarin.Forms.Core is 1.4.3.6374

there is no exceptions happens, here is my log after home button pressed:

```
07-07 01:45:48.861 D/Mono    ( 5362): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android[0x74617de0] -> System.Xml[0x78a1b718]: 4
07-07 01:45:48.871 D/Mono    ( 5362): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0x78d0d3b8] -> System[0x755e5a18]: 13
07-07 01:45:48.956 D/Mono    ( 5362): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0x78d0d3b8] -> System.Core[0x75145c70]: 9
07-07 01:45:49.021 D/AbsListView( 5362): onDetachedFromWindow
```

after picking up from app stack

```
07-07 01:47:26.021 E/MoreInfoHPW_View( 5362): Parent view is not a TextView
07-07 01:47:26.066 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
07-07 01:47:26.066 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
07-07 01:47:26.066 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: right = -2
07-07 01:47:26.066 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = -2
07-07 01:47:26.076 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
07-07 01:47:26.076 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
07-07 01:47:26.076 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: right = -2
07-07 01:47:26.076 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = -2
07-07 01:47:26.086 D/Activity( 5362): #3 setTransGradationModeColor to false
07-07 01:47:26.131 D/AbsListView( 5362): Get MotionRecognitionManager
07-07 01:47:26.141 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
07-07 01:47:26.141 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
07-07 01:47:26.146 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: right = -2
07-07 01:47:26.146 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = -2
07-07 01:47:26.216 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
07-07 01:47:26.216 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
07-07 01:47:26.216 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: right = -2
07-07 01:47:26.216 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = -2
07-07 01:47:26.266 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: left = 273
07-07 01:47:26.266 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
07-07 01:47:26.266 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: right = 375
07-07 01:47:26.266 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 102
07-07 01:47:26.271 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
07-07 01:47:26.271 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
07-07 01:47:26.271 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: right = 150
07-07 01:47:26.271 D/ProgressBar( 5362): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 150
```

**UPD [FIXED]:**

suddenly, I fixed it!
here is my code:
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        private static App _app;

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        if (!_hasEverInited)
        {
            InitGeo();
            Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);
            ShareImplementation.Init(this);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            ImageCircleRenderer.Init();
            InitData();
            _hasEverInited = true;
        }
        if (_app == null)
            LoadApplication(_app = new App());
        else
        {
            LoadApplication(_app);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a common bug in Xamarin.Forms and some Android task managers. Here's a quick hack:

```
public class MainActivity : FormsApplicationActivity
{
    public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (this.ActionBar.Title == "YourMainMenuTitle")
        {
            if (keyCode == Keycode.Back && e.RepeatCount == 0)
            {
                MoveTaskToBack(true);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
    }

    ...
}
```